How to solve $ax^2 + bx + c = |kx + d|, x ≥ 0$?
So, I have a physical problem that looks like so:

A car is driving along a straight road at constant speed and at time 0 it starts emitting drones in all directions.
Drones start flying at the same speed as the car and constantly accelerate — some forward and some backwards.
For computational reasons, time is going to be a natural number, and the problem will be discretely approximated.
At what time will one of the drones reach a post stationed somewhere on this road?

I model this problem as a system like so:
$$
\begin{cases}
t (t + 1) / 2 = \left|y − (x_0 + vt)\right| \\
t ≥ 0
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
— Here: $x_0$ is the starting position, $y$ is the post, $v$ is the velocity; $t (t + 1) / 2$ is the farthest the drones can be from the car at time $t$ and $\left|y − (x_0 + vt)\right|$ is how far the car is from the post at time $t$. When the car is exactly as far from the post as the farthest the drones can be from the car — so, one of the drones will be at the post.
(I understand it is confusing why the drones move according to a formula for discrete sum $\sum t = t (t + 1) / 2$ and not the usual continuous $\int t = t^2/2$, but this is important for my problem. If you like, imagine that the drones jump like frogs.)
This system looks a bit complicated so I decide to first solve a «generic» case where on the left I have a quadratic function and on the right I have absolute value of a linear function. Like so:
$$
\begin{cases}
ax^2 + bx + c = |kx + d| \\
x ≥ 0
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
$$
My first step is to unfold the definition of absolute value. This gives me two cases:
$$
(a)
\begin{cases}
ax^2 + bx + c = kx + d \\
x ≥ 0 \quad
kx + d ≥ 0
\end{cases}
\quad
(b)
\begin{cases}
ax^2 + bx + c = − (kx + d) \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≤ 0
\end{cases}
\tag{3}
$$
Now these equations are simply quadratic equations, with coëfficients $α$, $β$ and $ς$:
$$
(a) \enspace
\begin{array}
ax^2 + bx + c = kx + d \\
\hline ax^2 + bx − kx + c - d = 0 \\
\hline ax^2 + (b − k)x + (c − d) = 0 \\
\hline α = a \quad β = b − k \quad ς = c − d
\end{array}
\quad
(b) \enspace
\begin{array}
ax^2 + bx + c = -(kx + d) \\
\hline ax^2 + bx + kx + c + d = 0 \\
\hline ax^2 + (b + k)x + (c + d) = 0 \\
\hline α = a \quad β = b + k \quad ς = c + d
\end{array}
\tag{4}
$$
Now, there are two general solutions to a quadratic equation:
$$
(α)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{+\sqrt{β^2 − 4ας} - β}{2α} \\
β^2 − 4ας ≥ 0
\end{cases}
\quad
(β)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{-\sqrt{β^2 − 4ας} - β}{2α} \\
β^2 − 4ας ≥ 0
\end{cases}
\tag{5}
$$
So, we have two quadratic equations and two solutions for each, with some bounds that tell us when these solutions are appropriate to the physical meaning of the problem — not imaginary and not negative. So, there are now 4 problems, like so:
$$
\scriptsize
\begin{array}
(aα)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{+\sqrt{(b − k)^2 − 4a(c − d)} - (b − k)}{2a} \\
(b − k)^2 − 4a(c − d) ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≥ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
(aβ)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{-\sqrt{(b − k)^2 − 4a(c − d)} - (b − k)}{2a} \\
(b − k)^2 − 4a(c − d) ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≥ 0
\end{cases} \\
& \\
(bα)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{+\sqrt{(b + k)^2 − 4a(c + d)} - (b + k)}{2a} \\
(b + k)^2 − 4a(c + d) ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≤ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
(bβ)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{−\sqrt{(b + k)^2 − 4a(c + d)} - (b + k)}{2a} \\
(b + k)^2 − 4a(c + d) ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≤ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
\end{array}
\tag{6}
$$
The differences are quite subtle and now it really begins to get confusing. We can maybe simplify a bit:
$$
\scriptsize
\begin{array}
(aα)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{+\sqrt{b^2 + k^2 − 4ac + 4ad − 2bk} - b + k}{2a} \\
b^2 + k^2 − 4ac + 4ad − 2bk ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≥ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
(aβ)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{-\sqrt{b^2 + k^2 − 4ac + 4ad − 2bk} - b + k}{2a} \\
b^2 + k^2 − 4ac + 4ad − 2bk ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≥ 0
\end{cases} \\
& \\
(bα)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{+\sqrt{b^2 + k^2 − 4ac − 4ad + 2bk} - b + k}{2a} \\
b^2 + k^2 − 4ac − 4ad + 2bk ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≤ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
(bβ)
\begin{cases}
x = \cfrac{−\sqrt{b^2 + k^2 − 4ac − 4ad + 2bk} - (b + k)}{2a} \\
b^2 + k^2 − 4ac − 4ad + 2bk ≥ 0 \\
x ≥ 0 \quad kx + d ≤ 0
\end{cases} & \quad
\end{array}
\tag{7}
$$
— But is this really helping? I am not even sure what I am supposed to be doing now.
For every equation, we have a quadratic boundary $b^2 + k^2 − 4ac ± 4ad ∓ 2bk ≥ 0$ in 4 dimensions $a$, $b$, $d$, $k$, a linear boundary $kx + d \enspace {\small ^≥/_≤} \enspace 0$ in $d$, $k$ and another, complicated boundary defined in terms of $x$. From the physical meaning we understand that these boundaries must partition the whole 4 dimensional space into 4 sets, so that each formula is applicable to one of 4 physically distinct cases:

The car may be going forward or backwards.
The post may be before or behind the car.

How does this follow from the mathematical situation at hand? Which inequalities describe which conditions? How do I prove that for any given $a$, $b$, $d$, $k$ (with $a ≠ 0$) exactly one formula applies?

I don't know how you got that equation.  If your car's position at time $t$ is $x_0 + v t$, and at time $0$ you emit drones with acceleration $a$ (i.e. accelerating forward) and $-a$ (i.e. accelerating backward), the forward drone's position at time $t$ is $x_0 + v t + a t^2/2$ and the backward drone's position is $x_0 + vt - a t^2/2$.  Assuming $a > 0$ and $v > 0$, $x_0 + v t + a t^2/2$ is increasing for $t > 0$, and it will reach position $y$ (if $y > x_0$) when $x_0 + v t + at^2/2 = y$: one solution $t = (-v + \sqrt{v^2 - 4 (x_0 - y) a/2}$.

On the other hand, there may be $0$, $1$ or $2$ times $t > 0$ when the backward drone reaches position $y$.

Breaking the absolute value down into two cases for $kx + d \ge 0$ and $kx + d \le 0$ is how I'd approach this problem too.

You introduce too many variables for them all to be describe the situation at hand. Either $v>0$ or $v<0$ and either $y-x_0>0$ or $y-x_0<0$. So you might be better served considering $t^2+t=|2d-2v|$, where $d=y-x_0$.

@RobertIsrael   I understand your confusion. The actual problem I am working on would have taken too much space to explain, so I tried to offer a simpler but still plausible problem. I am going to edit the question and add an explanation of why I have modelled the problem this way.

@RobertIsrael   I clarified this. Does it help?
